# Как правильно пользоваться заголовками HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

В приложении один единственный экземпляр HttpClient

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Но есть куча методов запускаемые в разных потоках которые работают с HttpClient и задают ему заголовки.
Иногда потоки пересекаются и получается что по несколько раз пытаются задать один и тот же заголовок и вылетает исключение.

```
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("UserAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Charset", "utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
```

Вот как сделать так, чтобы я мог менять заголовки, но не получал исключения xD

Т.е. для каждого запроса чтобы у меня были свои заголовки, пусть иногда они и одинаковые.

[MSDN HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: А вы уверены, что эти заголовки вам надо постоянно устанавливать? Ведь `UserAgent`, это по сути название вашего приложение, либо нечто, что требует сайт и в этих целях обычно достаточно один раз установить и забыть. Ну а `Accept-Charset`, это вообще лишний заголовок, который ооооочень редко на что либо влияет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я пока не особо знаю что мне из этого будет нужно, а что нет. Плюс не все скопировал в пример. Но что если я захочу для каждого запроса использовать свой 'UserAgent' или нужен будет разный 'Referer' и что то там ещё. А вот сделать этого пока не могу xD

Comment: каждому запросу можно установить свои headers, дефолтные на то и дефолтные, что используются для всех

Comment: @Grundy вооот, то что нужно, как это делается ?

Comment: Метод [`.SendAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_SendAsync_System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_) принимает  [`HttpRequestMessage`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=net-5.0) в котором и можно задать необходимые заголовки, которые перепишут дефолтные

Comment: @Vipz Я бы на вашем месте научился бы вычислять то, что нужно, а что нет, ибо те заголовки, что вы дали, это чаще всего лишний мусор, который либо вовсе не нужен, либо нужен как некое общее значение, установленное один раз. А так да, как вам сказали выше, Default это общие заголовки, перейдите на уровень ниже при помощи `HttpRequestMessage` и уже ему ставьте нужные заголовки.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо! Постараюсь разобраться.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если дефолтные не трогать. То получается я HttpClietnt-у не смогу задавать рандомные заголовки для каждого запроса ?

Comment: @Vipz Я вам не говорю, что нельзя или не делайте (как поступить вон ответ уже выше в комментах), просто говорю, что это лишняя работа в большинстве случаев. Ну вот допустим вы на SO отправляете запрос с `UserAgent`'ом от мобильного телефона, а допустим на google отправляете запрос с `UserAgent`'ом уже браузера Edge (PC), ок, отправили, но зачем..? Если сайт требует тот же `UserAgent`, то ему зачастую достаточно любого "реального". По этому я вам и говорю, определитесь что именно вам надо отправлять сайту, что он **требует** и из 20+ заголовков у вас в итоге на сайт пойдет 1-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultRequestHeaders` они на то и Default, что они по умолчанию. Они оптимизированы для быстродействия, то есть на добаление этих заголовоков в каждый запрос уйдет меньше времени, чем если вы будете добавлять их непосредственно в запрос. Чтобы добавить заголовок в запрос, можно использовать `HttpRequestMessage`.

К примеру, вам нужно выполнить GET запрос. Тогда метод получения страницы будет выглядеть примерно так:

```cs
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async Task<string> GetHtmlPageAsync(string url)
{
    using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36");
    request.Headers.AcceptCharset.ParseAdd("utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    // response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // бросает исключение если сервер вернул ошибку
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```