# Как сделать http запрос с заголовками?

Tags: c#, http, requests, http-заголовки

Как я могу выполнить http запрос с использованием своих заголовков на языке программирования c#?
На python это выглядит так:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "sid": "sid1",
    "sid2": "sid2",
    "sid3": "sid3"
}

response = requests.get("http://example.com/", headers=headers).json()
```

На JavaScript кажется так:

```
const fetch = require("fetch");

let headers = {
    "sid": "sid1",
    "sid2": "sid2",
    "sid3": "sid3"
};

let response;
fetch("http://example.com/", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers
}.then(data => data.json())
.then(data => { response = data; };
```

Comment: А что вы пробовали? Не уж то в интернете (даже тут, на SO) нету ответа на ваш вопрос? Вот пишем в любом поисковике `c# get запрос`, попадаем на документацию, видим, что там используется некий `WebRequest`, гуглим что это, видим на офф сайте `Не рекомендуется использовать WebRequest ... используйте HttpClient`, понимаем теперь что в C# отвечает за HTTP запросы. Ну а дальше, дело пары минут, где вам либо IDE подскажет какой метод использовать, либо вы найдете в документации или тут, на SO нужную вам информацию.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1232436/179763